# How to fix setError message appear in different languages?

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-textinputlayout, material-components

I created a login page and this page support 2 different languages **(English and French)**.

The page works fine when i translate from language to language.

But the problem is when i switch to **french language** the **setError message** does not appear anymore for the fields validations.

This code will load the page based on lang selection:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.eng:
                String languageToLoad = "en";
                Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                break;

                case R.id.fr:
                languageToLoad = "fr";
                locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                break;

                default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And here is the validation for Username field and the **setError message**:

```
private boolean validateUsername(){

        String username = usernameEditText.getText().toString().trim();

        if(username.isEmpty()){

            usernameEditText.setError("Field can't be empty");
            return false;

        } else if(username.length() > 15){

            usernameEditText.setError("Username too long");
            return false;

        } else {
            usernameEditText.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The XML code:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/YourUsername"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="15"
        app:errorEnabled="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signupButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/test3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="signupLogin"
        android:hint="@string/login" />
</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

The popup msg between the 2 languages:

[image: English Language Msg] [image: French Language without popup]

Here i set the error message in **English** but what are the ways to add to setError message to support different languages ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `setError` message from String resource and use localization string for preferred language with english

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/username"
    ..>

TextInputLayout username = findViewById(R.id.username);
username.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.xxxx));
```

Then just define the string in `res/values/strings.xml` and `res/values-fr/strings.xml`

Comment: Hello @Gabriele Mariotti i also tried your step but nothing happen when i switch the language the popup message does not appear when i click on login button.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can Localize your app. Refer this link [Localize your app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization#creating-alternatives)

GoTo **res** -> **values** -> **Right Click** -> **New** -> **Value Resource File** -> **Select Locale** -> **Add French** -> **OK**

[image: Localize your app]

**string.xml**

```
<string name="empty_error">Field can't be empty</string>
<string name="character_exceed_error">Username too long </string>
```

**string.xml(fr)**

```
<string name="empty_error">Le champ ne peut pas être vide</string>
<string name="character_exceed_error">Nom d'utilisateur trop long </string>
```

Nou you just need to get string value from resources Like below

```
usernameEditText.setError(getString(R.string.empty_error);
```

Comment: Hello @Rajnish suryavanshi ! I followed your steps and i updated my code to  usernameEditText.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.empty_error)); but in french lang the error remain the same when i click on login button nothing happens the popup message does not appear.